# Need to detect whenever the displayed lines change in an ITextView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing an extension that has manages some adornments. Some of these can span several text lines. The idea is that the adornment is associated with every line in the span. So, even though the top line scrolls off the top, I want to display a translated/clipped version of the adornment over the remaining lines.

I was expecting the ITextView.LayoutChanged event to trigger whenever the view is scrolled (as described in the "Inside the Editor" article in MSDN). However, in some circumstances it doesn't. Namely, when scrolling past the end of the file. Since no new lines need to be formatted, no LayoutChanged is triggered. This means that eventually the line my adornment is attached to is no longer in TextViewLines, so the adornment disappears.

Unfortunately, there is no ViewportTopChanged event in the ITextView. (Strange that there are view-port left, width, and height change events, but no top change event.) I tried using an IScrollMap to detect the scroll, but it's MappingChanged event does not trigger in in this situation either.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I was getting the results I posted before, but now I seem to be getting the LayoutChanged event at the end of the file now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ITextBuffer.Changed event, this event is fired whenever the content of the textview changes (addition / deletion / modification)...  See more here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextbuffer.changed.aspx